# How to calculate intersection of two span?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I wonder how to calculate the expression below?
does anybody have an idea about it?

$ span\{\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 \\
        d & 0 \\
        0 & 0\\
        0 & 0\\
        0 & k\\
        \end{bmatrix}\}^{\perp} \bigcap span\{\begin{bmatrix}
                                               1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                               0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                               0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
                        \} $

There is a related question about mine about how to calculate the Annihilator for matrix in
[Find a basis for $\mathbf{W}^{\perp}$ given spanning vectors of $\mathbf{W}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21757/find-a-basis-for-mathbfw-perp-given-spanning-vectors-of-mathbfw)

but still, I don't know how to calculate the intersection!

Comment: What does $\bot$ mean here, $\top$ (orthogonality)?

Comment: For the second span, is scalar times that matrix or the span of the column vectors of that matrix meant? Or the row vectors..

Comment: @mvw its the span of the column vector of that matrix

Comment: @mvw The symbol stands for orthogonality as you have mentioned.